# Поиск по никнейму

Tags: spring

Хочу реализовать функцию поиска по нику

```
@GetMapping("/findByName")
    public String find(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String filter, Model model) {
        Iterable<User> users;

        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
            users = userRepo.findByUsername(filter);
        } else {
            users = userRepo.findAll();
        }

        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("filter", filter);

        return "findByName";
    }
```

Но выдает ошибку

> java: incompatible types: com.example.photoalbum.domain.User cannot be
> converted to java.lang.Iterable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findByUsername` возвращает один объект.

Если нужно вернуть список используйте `findAllByUsername` или явно заворачивайте объект в список:

```
  users = Arrays.asList(userRepo.findByUsername(filter));
```